# services.AddMvc() isn't found on aspnetcore v2.1.1

Tags: asp.net-core

I migrated to aspnetcore 2.1.1, and took the recommended action of removing Microsoft.AspNetCore.**All** and replacing it with Microsoft.AspNetCore.**App**. As a result, I had to add a number of other packages (which makes sense), but I can't find any package that resolves the error about not being able to find AddMvc() on IServiceCollection.

In other words, services.AddMvc() throws a compile-time error.

It is resolved by adding the *.**All** package, so I know it's in there somewhere.

```
$ dotnet --version
2.1.301
```

My using statements:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
```

Anyone know what I'm missing, or is this by design? Are we expected to use the "All" package, or are we expected to use the "App" package and use AddMvcCore() with options to enable MVC?

Help is always appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed Microsoft Net Core SDK 2.1.301, Net Core Runtime 2.1.1 and Asp Net Core Runtime 2.1.1 in your system?

Comment: UseMvc method should be appear by adding Microsoft.AspNetCore.App (2.1.1). This depends on Microsoft.AspNetcore.Mvc (2.1.1) and this depends on Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (2.1.1). In the latter library is the method.

Comment: You guys are right. When I removed the package and re-added it, it worked. Just a Visual Studio fluke me thinks. Thanks for the responses.